# Juxtaposing a formula onto a graph in r

Tags: r, plot

Here's what I have so far:

```
plot(c(-2,2), c(0,4))
text(0, 2, labels= expression(EMA[1]~ "=" ~ ((P[i]*alpha)+ (EMA[i-1]*(1-alpha)))))
```

[image]

I need it to look like the attached formula. I feel like I need to use bquote or something of the like, but can't get it to work in context.

[image]

Comment: In what way is is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly this:

```
plot(c(-2,2), c(0,4))
LABEL <- expression(EMA[1] == (P[i] %*% alpha) + (EMA[i-1] %*% (1 - alpha))
                    ~~ plain(where) ~~ alpha == frac(2, 1 + 30))
text(0, 2, labels = LABEL)
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. I like how you you used "plain" and made the label separately.